# swift height of the cell in the current View

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have couple of cells in table view. Now at any given point of time I want to calculate the current height of the cell in the view, i.e if it is 3/4th of through the view, It should return (cellheight)*3/4 height.

I have calculated the current view in following way:

`let visibleRect = CGRect(origin: tableView.contentOffset, size: tableView.bounds.size)`

Now as and when I stop scrolling, I want to find the current height of the cell of particular indexpath, which I have calculated here.

`let visiblePoint = CGPoint(x: visibleRect.midX, y: visibleRect.midY)
 let visibleIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForRow(at: visiblePoint)!`

I hope I am clear. Thanks for the help.

Cheers!

Comment: What is your issue?, How i can help you?

Comment: I need the height of the cell in the view. I mean, if the actual height of cell is 500 and its halfway up, i want to get that height then.

Basically, i want to check the height of cell in the view with respect to the current offset.

Comment: You need the heigth of the cell in the middle of your visible section of your tableView is that what you need?

Comment: not middle exactly. for any given indexPath which is in the view, I need the height of the visible portion of that cell. It can be anything, ranging from 0 to its defined height.

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `UITableViewCell` after you have the desired indexPath is easy you need yo call this method `self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexpath)` after that you can access to frame of your cell, and making an intersection with your previously calculated `visibleRect` you must have what you need

```
      if let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexpath) as? UITableViewCell
        {
            let intersection = cell.frame.intersection(visibleRect)
            debugPrint(intersection.size.height)
        }
```

Comment: Damn! This just skipped my mind. This has been exactly what i was looking for. Many thanks to you for quick and prompt reply.  Cheers!

Comment: I am glad to help you!, happy coding @AakashDave

Comment: I had got the cell but really forgot to use the intersection. Thanks Again!